# How not to overwrite RecyclerView list when adding an item in Room Database

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-room, android-livedata

I recently started programming in android and I have a problem about `RecyclerView` and `LiveData`:

when I delete or add an item in my RoomDatabase, LiveData changes correctly and my observer starts. I have items that can be checked but, when I delete or add an item in RecyclerView, they are overwritten and I lose every checked item. I've tried to use `DiffUtil` but I think that I've sadly misunderstood its usage.

I've seen every tutorial on yt, medium and StackOverflow but each one overwrites the data. isn't it ineffective when I have n complex-items?

Any suggestions about how not to lose checked information?

I don't want to save checked information in roomDatabase because when I restart the application there must be no checked items.

Extract of myPlace class and Room Entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "myPlaces")
public class MyPlace {

    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    private String place_id;
    private String name;
    private String reference;
    @TypeConverters(GeometryConverter.class)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "geometry")
    @SerializedName("geometry")
    private Geometry geometry;
    private String vicinity;
    @Ignore
    private boolean checked;
    @Ignore
    private Bitmap image;
    ...
    }
```

LiveData Observer:

```
...
        LiveData<List<MyPlace>> liveData = favoriteViewModel.getFavoritePlaces();
        liveData.observe(this, myPlaces -> {

                    recyclerView.setAdapter(myFavoritePlacesAdapter);
                    myFavoritePlacesAdapter.setFavoritePlaces(new ArrayList<>(myPlaces));

                    ...
                };
```

In my Adapter:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyFavoritePlaceViewHolder holder,final int position) {
        final MyPlace myPlace = favoritePlaces.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
        holder.bind(myPlace);
        holder.place.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if((listener != null)){
                holder.place.setChecked(myPlace.isChecked());
                listener.onItemClick(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });
        holder.place.setOnLongClickListener(v -> {
            if (listener != null) {
                myPlace.setChecked(!myPlace.isChecked());
                holder.place.setChecked(myPlace.isChecked());
                listener.onItemLongClick(position);
            }
            return true;
        });
```

Comment: isn't it ineffective when I have n complex-items? `no` 
your other solution would be to keep a reference.

Comment: To save checked information, you can use either the new `recyclerview-selection` library (I think, I never used it), or keep a `Set<MyPlace>` to keep track of selected items. As for `DiffUtil`, yes, I agree that it is incredibly less efficient that keeping the same list and making modifications yourself, but in the end that makes very little difference, except easier development. With <1000 items you shouldn't have any performance concerns. Over that, use Paging.

Comment: @forthelulx well, yes but when overwrite data I think that I should re-retrieve image from Places-sdk because google, in tos, doesn't permit cashing its images and recreate interface for every item. So i lose my previous work (or am I missing something?)

Comment: @Ggwppino `DiffUtil` doesn't overwrites the data totally. It generates minimum required updates that are required on an old list to convert it into the new list. Finally, those updates can be dispatched to the appropriate adapter to make the necessary changes only.